# Set a dynamic infoWindow to a dynamic marker's onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to set dynamic infowindows to the onclick function of dynamic marker's, but I can't quite seem to make it work.

Currently what happens is when I click one of the marker's it show the same data on both of them. I can understand the the problem here is that my variable "i" is always the same, that's why I always do i-2, but I can't quite seem to understand why the value is always the last value of the variable instead of the current one in the supposed iteration.

Here is the code that takes care of the markers and infowindows:

```
function doMarkers() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/resources/scripts/php/conn/ajax/getEmployeeMap.php",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {
            clearMarkers();
            var data = response;
            var i = 1;
            while (i <= Object.keys(data).length) {
                geocoder.geocode({'address': data[i]}, function (results, status) {
                    if (status == 'OK') {
                        var geomarker = results[0].geometry.location;
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: geomarker
                        });
                        marker.setMap(map);

                        var infoContent = '<p>Address: </p>' + data[i - 2];
                        console.log(data[i - 2]);

                        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                            content: infoContent
                        });

                        infoWindows.push(infoWindow);


                        marker.addListener('click', function () {
                            infoWindows[i -2].open(map, marker);
                        });

                        console.log(markers.length);
                        markers.push(marker);
                    }
                });
                i++;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try it like that:

```
function doMarkers() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/resources/scripts/php/conn/ajax/getEmployeeMap.php",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(response) {
            clearMarkers();
            var data = response;
            var i = 1;
            while (i <= Object.keys(data).length) {
                geocoder.geocode({
                    'address': data[i]
                }, function(results, status) {
                    if (status == 'OK') {
                        var geomarker = results[0].geometry.location;
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: geomarker
                        });
                        marker.setMap(map);

                        var infoContent = '<p>Address: </p>' + data[i - 2];
                        console.log(data[i - 2]);

                        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                            content: infoContent
                        });

                        marker.addListener('click', function() {
                            infoWindow.open(map, marker); //directly add the event to the info window
                        });

                        infoWindows.push(infoWindow); //add it after adding your event

                        console.log(markers.length);
                        markers.push(marker);
                    }
                });
                i++;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Works flawlessly, just gonna add a small thing to your answer ;)

Comment: Like the actual reason ^^ ? I think (not sure) that it had something to do with the fact that you were accessing the array of infoWindows by id just after pushing an element into it. So that moved the ids.

Comment: using the infoWindow variable instead of the array worked like a charm, but I was doing a similar mistake above when I was doing var infoContent = '<p>Address: </p>' + data[i - 2]; what fixed that same mistake that I did and you fixed, and the one here was doing date[markers.length + 1]